# Expose WCF service and use it on the existing ASP application using only one Web Role on Azure platform

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-web-roles

I'm new to Azure platform and I'm trying to create an Azure application that have an ASP application and a WCF service.

It is possible to expose the WCF service to other applications and to use it on the existing ASP application using only one Web Role?

If it is possible, how can I do that? If not, what are the alternatives?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, just add the WCF service (*.svc + service dll) to the ASP.NET project. IIS will be able to serve request for both. Make sure you put the required configuration into your web.config.

It is not the only solution but it should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be be use the Full IIS Web Role and have one site for your Web App, and another for WCF.